# Symbol being recognised as part of a string in my Java program?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have started the process of creating a program that replaces capital lettered words with asterisks that match the length of the capitalised word. However, in the example below, you can see that it considers a full stop (.) to be part of the word.

Could somebody explain to me why my program is recognising a full stop (.) as a part of the string?

The out put of the code is:

`** was in *****`

Whereas, I expect it to be:

`** was in ****.`

```
public class redact {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* String to split. */
        String stringToSplit = "It was in July.";

        String[] tempArray;

        /* delimiter */
        String delimiter = " ";

        /* given string will be split by the argument delimiter provided. */
        tempArray = stringToSplit.split(delimiter);

        /* print substrings */

        for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(tempArray[i].charAt(0))) {
                int length = tempArray[i].length();
                tempArray[i] = "";

                for(int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                    tempArray[i] += ('*');
                }   
                System.out.print(" " + tempArray[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.print(" " + tempArray[i]);
            }

            // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on how to escape it please?

Comment: You split the string on white space. There is no white space between `July`and `.`. `tempArray[3]`is `July.`, and not `July` as you expect

Comment: check if the character is a letter before turning it to a *

Comment: @Poppo123 yes because `tempArray[3]` is `July.` not `July` as mentioned by @jhamon.

Comment: Okay, I used this: if (Character.isUpperCase(tempArray[i].charAt(0)) && Character.isAlphabetic(tempArray[i].charAt(-1))) but now I get a String index out of range: -1 exception

Comment: You are calling charAt(-1). What functionality are you expecting from doing this?

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. By calling -1 im looking for the last character? Which in the case of July. is the . symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split the string on white space. There is no white space between `July` and `.`. `tempArray[3]` is `July.`, and not `July` as you expect.

One way to do what you want is to check if each character of the word is a letter, and then replace it with a `*`. So you need to keep each elements of `tempArray`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {

  if (Character.isUpperCase(tempArray[i].charAt(0))) {

    int length = tempArray[i].length();
    //            tempArray[i] = "";
    String result = "";

    for(int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      if (Character.isLetter(tempArray[i].charAt(j))) {
        result += ('*');
      } else {
        result += tempArray[i].charAt(j);
      }
    }

    System.out.print(" " + result);

  }

  else {
    System.out.print(" " + tempArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes I see what you're saying, thank you so much!